# Class conforming to too many protocols?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

So I've been building an app for a while now and over time one of my classes (a UIViewController) has grown quite large, doing quite a lot of stuff with one view.  As such, I've had to make it conform to a lot of protocols (12 now).  I'm now starting to worry that I'm conforming to a few too many.

Is there a problem with conforming to a lot of protocols in one class?  Will there be a performance hit or anything like that?  I'm not looking for personal opinions, but rather things like possible performance issues or if it's against a best-practices/style guide document (such as one distributed by Apple).

Some of the protocols my class conforms to (excluding a few custom protocols):

```
UIAlertViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, 
UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIBarPositioningDelegate, 
ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate
```

***Edit:***
As noted by a few of the answers, the majority of the protocols are UI related - and the view itself is not cluttered.  `UIAlertViewDelegate`, `UIActionSheetDelegate`, `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`, and `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` are all displayed separately (modally in the last two cases).  `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` are simply to handle a table.  `UITextFieldDelegate` is used to manage searching for the field (in order to allow me to check if the entered text is 'valid').  `UIBarPositioningDelegate` is required for iOS7 for appearance.
The class isn't overly large and only handles itself, without too much coupling (at least, in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

**From official apple documentation:**

> Tip: If you find yourself adopting a large number of protocols in a
>   class, it may be a sign that you need to refactor an overly-complex
>   class by splitting the necessary behavior across multiple smaller
>   classes, each with clearly-defined responsibilities. One relatively
>   common pitfall for new OS X and iOS developers is to use a single
>   application delegate class to contain the majority of an application’s
>   functionality (managing underlying data structures, serving the data
>   to multiple user interface elements, as well as responding to gestures
>   and other user interaction). As complexity increases, the class
>   becomes more difficult to maintain.

So the answer is that it is not bad to do so in terms of performance, but it is not a good practice.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Answer (score 1):

There is not penalty in having a class conforming to vary many protocols -- apart from negligible higher compilation time/space (due to having bigger compilation tables for that class, but this is really not meaningful, IMO) and possibly a class readability issue.

Indeed, when you specify that a class conform to a protocol you are simply telling the compiler to add all the methods declared inside of that protocol to the class interface. This has practically no impact either on performance or memory occupation.

The main issue you have is, IMO, about class readability. As in general you have an issue when your class offers too many public methods. This makes difficult to understand what the class is for. Refactoring would be strongly suggested, but again, this has nothing to do with performance.

From what you pasted, it seems that the protocols you are adding to your class seemingly relate to UI elements that you are managing inside of that class. Then, either the view you class manages is overly complex, or you need those delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for programming in general is to separate concerns and functions as much as possible. To me, it looks like your app consists of one crowded controller. Why is that? Too much code in one class or file makes it harder to debug and maintain, plus your interface must be really cluttered if you have all those elements in them. I can't give specific advice without seeing more code, but in general, you have too many thing in one controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this cause any performance penality‎ or  error.

But it seems that you class is very coupled, which is a bad design practice, but that's not necessary true, how much line of code you class have?

If that's a lot and you fell that you class is doing some work that it shouldn't you can refractor your code.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot tell you about performance without actually seeing code, but its possible that if somehow the two or more protocols declare ***identically named*** methods (it has happened to me) then you will get unexpected behavior which could include degraded performance. Suppose that two protocols define a basic method such as `- (void)update` and now you are only implementing one update method, but both protocols want to use it so at best you are getting too many calls to update (degraded performance). if one of the protocols defines the method as @optional then its not always immediately obvious something bad is happening.

What I can tell you is that this kind of monolithic design is universally considered poor. It sound like you have a big [ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud) going on.

Comment: wow a downvote for saying pretty much exactly what the other answers are saying :)

Comment: (I did not downvote, but) I do not think that "unexpected behavior" or "multithreading" would be a problem if a class is declared as conforming to many protocols.

Comment: @MartinR thanks that makes sense, I guess I wasn't clear enough that I mean if two protocols define the same method you could see problems.